# Record/Capture a discontinuous audio stream with ffmpeg

Tags: networking, audio, ffmpeg, streaming, rtp

I want to record an audio stream using ffmpeg. The problem is, that this stream is not available over the whole timespan, that I want to record.
I have a device which takes input from a microphone, encodes it and broadcasts a rtp stream. This device can be controlled to start and stop this stream via a button (or a telnet command).

So basicly I want to start a recording session. ffmpeg should capture this rtp stream, if the stream is available. Otherwise silence audio should be recorded and when the stream is available again, it should record this stream again and so on.

How can I achieve this? When I start ffmpeg, it always aborts at the time the stream ends.

For now my ffmpeg command just looks like this:

`ffmpeg -i rtp://192.168.2.255:3131 out.wav`

If this is not possible with a ffmpeg command what will be the best (or easiest) way to do this.

Comment: Have you found a solution?I have a similar problem.

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer. I solved my problem by recording the stream in a C# programm. I've written a class to parse the rtp packets, extract the audio data and write the bytes in a MemoryStream, if the stream is available. If the stream is not available I write bytes with the value 0 for silence (depends on the audio format) to this MemoryStream. The number of how many bytes you have to write for 1 second, should be: `SampleRate * (BitsPerSample / 8)`

Comment: Thanks, but it requires more skills then I have :)

Comment: @d03090 How do you determine to write silence? I mean, if for some reason the broadcasting is halted, for say 2 seconds, ffmpeg doesn't record silence, it simply waits for new data to come from the source. So how do you know if the stream was available or not?

Comment: @Luke Like I said in an above comment. I solved my problem now within C#. Sadly I still don't know how this could work with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to record when there is audio, and not record when there is silence using ffmpeg.  Try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://192.168.2.255:3131 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-30dB output-file.mp3
```

More details available here:  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to record silent audio data during the time the rtp stream is unavailable. e.g. the rtp stream is available for 5 seconds, then goes offline for 3 seconds and comes back online for 10 seconds. My goal is to now have a 18 seconds long continuous audio file, which contains 3 seconds of silence.

Comment: Is it possible to remove all parts before last `stop_threshold`?